# Is there a reason I'm getting IndexError: list index out of range on this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, indexing

I struggle a lot with recursion and my brain doesn't seem to be able to process this question apparently. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Question prompt: Write a recursive program that computes the product of all numbers in a given list.

```
def product(L):
    if L[0]==0:
        return 0
    else:
        if len(L) > 0:
            return L[0] * product(L[1:])
```

I thought first checking the length would always make sure to cover the empty list case.

Comment: You seem to expect that there will be a 0 in the list. Shouldn't you test whether the list is empty instead of testing it has a 0 in its first slot? Secondly, if you return 0 from the base case, don't you think that any multiplication with that 0 will remain 0?

Comment: Ah yeah I definitely got L[0] confused in the first portion of the function. I was checking the value of the first index rather than checking the if it was empty thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. `L[0]==0` checks if the first element in the list contains the value of `0`. It is *not* a check on the *length* of the list. In particular, if all of the elements in the list are nonzero, the recursive function will eventually call itself with an empty list and try to access `L[0]`, causing an `IndexError`.
2. The empty product has a value of `1`. Your base case should return `1`, not `0` -- doing the latter would cause the function to always output `0`.

Here is a recursive solution that fixes both of these issues:

```py
def product(L):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return L[0] * product(L[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

The other answer gives you code that will work, and succinctly points out where the problem is. This answer is intended more to show you how to figure out the solution for yourself.

### /Edit

It's often a good idea to pick a very small input and try to step through it yourself, on paper. In this case let's try

```py
product([1,2,3])
```

`L[0]` is 1, so we skip to the `else`, then `len(L)` is 3 so we `return 1 * product([2,3])`, and then we have

```py
product([2,3])
```

which we move into again. `L[0]` is 2, so we skip to the `else`, and then `len(L)` is 2 so we `return 2 * product([3])`. All good so far.

```py
product([3])
```

`L[0]` is 3, so skip to `else`, and `len(L)` is 1, so `return 3 * product([])`, and then

```py
product([])
```

`L[0]` is... ah, there is no `L[0]` - `L` is empty. That's where the `IndexError` is coming from. Now you know where the error is, you can fix it - move the check for the length of the list to before that (and add a base case) and you get

```py
def product(L):
    if len(L) > 0:
        if L[0] == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return L[0] * product(L[1:])
    else:
        return 1
```

which will work.

Comment: Thank you for walking me step by step through this. I see where I made my mistakes and hopefully this will help with future questions like this. I wasn't fully aware how the slice function worked before this I just knew it was suggested by our teacher.